# Find text within string template PHP

Tags: php, string, parsing, templates

I have a series of string templates, for example:

```
Confirmation Number: 1234
Other random number: 1231
Order Name: Something
```

What I'm trying to do is getting these numbers and names from the template and use them as variables...
I know it's very simple, but how would I go about doing this?

Cheers!

EDIT: The best approach for me to do this would be entering something like:

```
Confirmation Number: {CONFIRMATION_NUMBER}
Other random number: {OTHER_NUMBER}
Order Name: {ORDER_NAME}
```

And then get whatever's in the brackets from the template.

Comment: explode on colon? it's not exactly clear what you want

Comment: What were your findings via Stack/Google?

Comment: No, that wouldn't work... I'm pretty sure the answer is a regexp, I just don't know what the pattern would be.

Comment: What variables are you hoping to create? You need to add more detail to your question.

Comment: well im guessing as you still haven't explained your self clearly

Comment: Just added an edit, hopefully explaining myself better.

Comment: Just added an answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi something like this might do the trick.

```
preg_match('/^(?P<key>.+)\:\s*(?P<value>[\w]+)$/', $line, $match);
```

then use `$match['key']` and `$match['value']`

demo
http://regex101.com/r/eN1rW0/2

You might need a space in the value?

```
preg_match('/^(?P<key>.+)\:\s*(?P<value>[\w\s]+)$/', $line, $match);
```

Or anything in the value?

```
preg_match('/^(?P<key>.+)\:\s*(?P<value>.+)$/', $line, $match);
```

Demo

http://regex101.com/r/eN1rW0/3

To capture the `:` you just want to move that inside of the `(` capture group `)` like so

```
    preg_match('/^(?P<key>.+\:)\s*(?P<value>.+)$/', $line, $match);
```

Comment: just as long as value odes not contain !@@#%^ etc

Comment: Easy to change that.

Comment: Works great, thanks! Just one more thing, how can I change the key group to capture literally 'Confirmation number: ' or 'Order name: ', etc.?

Comment: Oh I will update it.

Comment: (?P<key>Confirmation Number: )(?P<value>.+) is as close as I'll get to what I want, thanks a lot for the answer!